# C++ Can't read from file and load into vector

Tags: c++, vector, file-io, ifstream

The problem is that I have a text file, with 1,000,000 to 10,000,000 lines - each lines holds a decimal value.

I tried this code:

```
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("file.txt");
    std::vector<double> v1v;
    double s;
    while(inData>>s){
        v1v.push_back(s);
        cout << "Success" << endl;
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to fill my vector at all. I've tried this approach too(note the number of lines in the file is 1048570):

```
    double a1[1048570];
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("file.txt");
    for (int i=0;i<1048570;i++){
        inData >> a1[i];
    }inData.close();
```

I don't understand why it's not working, it's running, but there is nothing stored in the vectors.

Comment: Did you verify that the file open operation succeeded? If not, you should start with that.

Comment: Along with this, your file may need to be in the same folder you are debugging from. Try using a path as well rather than just the file name. If the path fails, it could be that you did not open the file successfully.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using? In some IDEs you may need to have the file you're reading from in the main folder of your project (not in the source code folder). In Eclipse you need to put the file in the folder you see when you create an empty C project. Try navigating to the folder where the compiled executable is stored, placing the file there, and running it. Also, did you try debugging?